# Extract value from json in a database column using linq

Tags: c#, json, linq

Suppose I have two columns in my database table as below :

```
Id     Actions
--     -------
id1    [{"Id": "create", "Schema": {"Id": "create", "Type": "Create"}, "Workflow": "basic"}]
```

I want to extract the value of the `Workflow` and check if it equals `basic`, then create a list with the entries in the database that meet this condition.

What I have tried is:

```
var data = db.Where(wf => (string) JObject.Parse(wf.Actions)["Workflow"] == "basic").AsEnumerable();
```

Then I check:

```
if (data.Any()) 
{
   // do something
}
```

But the if statement throws me the following error:

```
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `JArray.Parse`:

```
var data = db.Where(wf => (string) JArray.Parse(wf.Actions)[0]["Workflow"] == "basic")
    .AsEnumerable();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your json object is actually json array, so you need to parse it to `JArray`.

Then, when getting the value from JToken, you need to call `.Value<string>`, then you can compare it to `"basic"` string.

```
var data = db.Where(wf => JArray.Parse(wf.Actions).FirstOrDefault()?["Workflow"].Value<string>() == "basic").ToList();
```